# Thread synchronization not working as thought

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class who is responsible to handle everything related to Google maps

The code below is a fragment of this class; in this fragment (processPaths method) I do a foreach to read a entire Marker list, where for each iteration I create a Path object and two objects who implements Runnable. One of these objects is a PathProducer, responsible to mount a JSON request, get the response, decode it and return a List of LatLng; the other will get the List of latLng created by the PathProducer and will notify the MapsActivity to add a Polyline based on this list. The Path object is shared by both Runnable objects (that's why I locked/synchronized this object, PathConsumer can't notify the MapsActivity to draw the Path before the PathProducer calculate it).

```
public void processPaths(){   

        int count = 1;
        for (Marker m : markerList) {
            Path path = new Path(from, m.getPosition());
            PathProducer producer = new PathProducer("Producer " + count, path);
            PathConsumer consumer = new PathConsumer("Consumer " + count, path);

            producer.run();
            consumer.run();

            count++;
        }

    }
```

Below are my Path, PathProducer and PathConsumer classes

Path:

```
package com.trackit.app.utilities;

import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Shanx on 19/09/2016.
 */
public class Path{

private static final String TAG = Path.class.getSimpleName();

private LatLng from;
private LatLng to;
private List<LatLng> waypoint = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
private boolean created = false;

public Path(LatLng from, LatLng to){

    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;

    Log.e(TAG, "Path going from " + from + " to " + to + " created.");

}    

public LatLng getFrom(){

    return from;

}

public LatLng getTo(){

    return to;

}

public boolean wasCreated(){

    return created;

}

public List<LatLng> getWaypoint(){

    return waypoint;

}

public void setWaypoint(List<LatLng> path){

    waypoint = path;

}

public void created(boolean path){

    created = path;

}
```

}

PathProducer:

```
package com.trackit.app.utilities;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;
import com.trackit.app.track_it_v002.MapsActivity;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Shanx on 16/09/2016.
 */
public class PathProducer implements Runnable {

    private String name;
    private String trackingMode = "walking";
    private Path path;

    public PathProducer(String name, Path path){

        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        findPath();

    }

    private String createRequestURL(LatLng from, LatLng to){

        return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + Double.toString
            (from.latitude) + "," + Double.toString( from.longitude) +     "&destination=" +
            Double.toString(to.latitude) + "," + Double.toString(to.longitude) +
            "&sensor=false&mode=" + trackingMode + "&alternatives=true&" +
            "key=< my personal key =) >";

    }

    public void findPath(){

        //Getting the URL
        String url = createRequestURL(path.getFrom(), path.getTo());

        //Showing a dialog till we get the route
        final ProgressDialog loading =     ProgressDialog.show(MapsActivity.mActivity, "Getting Route",
            "Please wait...", false, false);

        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Calling the method drawPath to draw the path
                    drawPath(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                }
            });

        //Adding the request to request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue =     Volley.newRequestQueue(MapsActivity.mActivity);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    //The parameter is the server response
    private void drawPath(String result) {

        //Calculating the distance in meters
        Double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(path.getFrom(), path.getTo());

        //Displaying the distance
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.mActivity, String.valueOf(distance + " Meters"), Toast.
            LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            //Parsing json
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            path.setWaypoint(PolylineEncoder.decodeA(encodedString));
            path.created(true);
            this.notify();
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

        }

    }

    public String getName(){

    return name;

}
```

}

PathConsumer:

```
package com.trackit.app.utilities;

import android.graphics.Color;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.trackit.app.track_it_v002.MapsActivity;

/**
 * Created by Shanx on 20/09/2016.
 */
public class PathConsumer implements Runnable {

    private String name;
    private Path path;

    public PathConsumer(String name, Path path){

        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (path) {
            while(!path.wasCreated()) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        MapsActivity.mActivity.getMap().addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .addAll(path.getWaypoint())
            .width(10)
            .color(Color.GREEN)
            .geodesic(true)
            .clickable(true)
        );

    }

    public String getName(){

        return name;

    }

}
```

The processPaths method is called after a button OnClick is triggered; this happens after I add some Markers in the GoogleMap object.

The problem is, after add some Marker in the map and call processPaths(), the app freezes. I'm not used to multithreading in Java, but I did some researches and I've read some post here but none was able to help me...

You guys can point what is my error? StackOverflow is always my last resort, when none of my friends works with a particular programming language =S

Comment: `path.wasCreated()` you never update that, so you have an infinite loop. also `.run` that's not how you invoke a thread. here you simply call the method. For the producer it is fine, as the work on the ui needs to be done on the main thread, but on the consumer side, that effectively locks the ui, hence the freeze.

Comment: I'm doing this in the Android Studio, so when I call PathProducer or PathConsumer.start() the compiler cannot resolve the identifier, that's why i've called run() =S; I forgot to change the boolean state indeed, I will change that and report later

Comment: yes, you can only call `start` on an object that has a `start` method. You need to wrap your Runnable in a Thread.

Comment: Well I've called path.created(true) before the notify in the PathProducer code. But I got a java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait() in the PathConsumer run() --> This is strange and probably I'm doing wrong, but I should lock the object who is shared by both Producer and Consumer right?

Comment: I've changed some instructions like wait() to path.wait() because in some posts people said you should use <blocked obj>.wait() to say you want your runnable wait someone finish his job over the locked obj, and I change notify() to path.notify for the same reason, but I'm still getting the java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait() in the PathConsumer run() and I don't know why =S

Comment: yeah, you have to aquire a lock on the object before waiting on it (using a synchronized block). You probably don't want/need to go there yet, though, that gets pretty hairy.

Comment: Tahnks for your support, I need to look some concepts about multithreading in Java again =)